# Yii2 - Migrating test database

Tags: yii, yii2, codeception

I'm using codeception and I'm trying to run the migration for the test database.

From inside the tests folder I run the command

> php codeception/bin/yii migrate/up --interactive=0

but I'm getting the error

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

in /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php:205

Stack trace:
#0 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(261): yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(180): yii\di\ServiceLocator->setComponents(Array)
#2 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('components', Array)
#3 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#4 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#5 /www/shopboxyii-v2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#6 /www/shopboxyii-v2/tests/codeception/bin/yii(25): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#7 {main}
```

Does anyone know anything about this error or what's causing it??

Comment: What is your configuration for `user` in console config file?

Comment: why do you have the `user` component defined in the `console.php` or `console/config/main.php` file? if i am not wrong you dont need it there.

Comment: You were both right. I checked my yii file and there I could found the configuration file that had a configuration for the user. I removed this part and everything worked fine. 
Can any of you put an answer, and Ill mark it correct for people who might face the same problem.
And thanks alot for the solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the user component configuration in the `console/config/main.php` (if using `advanced-app`) or `app/config/web.php` (if using `basic-app`), you should just remove the component configurations and it will start working seamlessly.